# Is it possible to create an instance of an empty IQueryable without doing a call to the database?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

Calling the `datacontext.Things` will return an `IQueryable<Thing>`. But in my case the active user may not have rights to see any *Thing*. In this case I'd like to return an empty IQueryable of Things from my repository. Up untill now I used

```
return new Enumerable.Empty<Thing>.AsQueryable();
```

to pull this off and this has worked fine.

We made some developments and now, later on, the Queryable gets joined with another IQueryable. Executing that throws the following exception:

```
An IQueryable that returns a self-referencing Constant expression is not supported.
```

This happens because linq cannot join an actual IQueryable with something that acts like an IQueryable but is actually an Enumerable.

I have looked around on SO for a solution to this and the only alternative I found was using

```
return datacontext.Things.Take(0);
```

Eventhough this fixes the above problem since it returns an actual IQueryable, I assume it also actually does a call to the database which seems like an unnescessary waist of time since I know beforehand that the call is not going to return any records. Or is linq2Sql smart enough to not actually execute this query?

Is there a way to create an empty IQueryable that can still be used in a join without doing a call to the database?

Comment: " I assume it also actually does a call to the database which seems like an unnescessary waist of time since I know beforehand that the call is not going to return any records" why assume? Why don't you just check if any query was done? SSMS allows this, for example

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make EF do things it's not designed to do. Also passing round `IQueryable` like this is odd. If people aren't supposed to access a particular area, then I'm sure there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Oh, and yes, `Take(0)` will still hit the database, but with a `WHERE 1 = 0` clause (cc @CamiloTerevinto)

Comment: Are you really using linq-to-sql or EF?  EF has pretty much replaced linq-to-sql at this point.

Comment: I'm using linq-to-sql. Not EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Take` returns *a query*, not the results of that query.  As such, it does *not* interact with the database.  It is only if/when you iterate it that the query is executed and it's results accessed, potentially interacting with a database if the query was defined to need it.

In your case you're apparently using that query to compose it with another query, so it is only the new composite query that, when executed, will actually interact with the database.

That is unless you sometimes iterate that returned value and sometimes compose it into more complex queries.  In that case you probably need to just...not do that.  The query framework you're using will only allow you to compose queries that, if iterated, would actually query the database.  You could of course write your own query framework that behaved differently, but that would be very non-trivial.

Comment: "potentially interacting with a database if the query was defined to need it" (...) "The query framework you're using will only allow you to compose queries that, if iterated, would actually query the database" - Are these two statements contradicting? First you state that it is possible for a query to not fire to the db, but then you state that the framework I am using won't allow it. Is this possibility proposed in the first statement only applicable to other frameworks then? Or am I misreading this?

Comment: @Fuzzy It's possible to write an `IQueryable` that may or may not use the DB.  The query framework you're using won't allow you to embed a subquery unless that subquery would be querying that same database.  You can do other things with an `IQueryable` though besides embedding them in a subquery of a particular query provider's query.  Mostly commonly executing it without embedding it in another query.